# Is it a 6-base number system?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

We have 2 hands, and each has 5 fingers. I was wandering, if we create a 6-based system for hand, then we can have a number of 2 digit with 2 hands, that give the maximum of 35. Right?

Comment: Note that using each finger as a binary bit gives you a maximum of 31 on just one hand, and 1023 on two hands.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yep. In base $6$, you'd count up to 5, and then you'd need an agreement on what the next finger means. It sounds like you mean, the second digit in base 6 with the second hand, for a maximum of 55 in base 6,which is $5\cdot 6^0+5\cdot 6^1=35$.